# Get ASP.NET application name with NLog

Tags: asp.net, web-config, nlog

I am trying to figure out how to get the application name to be included in my file name when configuring NLog.  Here is an example:

```
<target name="trace" xsi:type="File" FileName="C:\MyApp_${date:format=yyyyMMdd}-trace.log" layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

However, I cant seem to be able to figure out what variable I need to use to pull the name of my application.  I wish it to be something like:

```
<target name="trace" xsi:type="File" FileName="C:\${AppName}_${date:format=yyyyMMdd}-trace.log" layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

I have gone through documentation here, https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers but none of them seem to be able to get my application name, the best I have found is the `${basedir}` but that gives me the full path.

Is there a way to configure this?

The purpose of this is to have a single configuration file that is referenced by multiple applications, however they all would have their own log files.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Windows service?

Comment: @Julian it is a .NET MVC5 website.

Comment: So you need the application name in IIS? Or the website name?

Comment: @Julian basically I have a website called Green.Common.Pallet (that is the name of the project file) and I am trying to pull that name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edit: From the edited description I understand that you like to read the website name in IIS for a MVC 5 application.

You can use the `${iis-site-name}` renderer for that.

You need to install NLog.Web NuGet package for that. No additional configuration is needed.

Comment: What if this was a console application, would I have to use a different tag?  Or in my case its looking like it might end up being a mix, is there a common one that can do this?

Comment: With a console app, `${processname}` could be the one you're looking for (in NLog package)